How to infer generic parameter in constructor?
The code infer map keys type as unknown, how to make it work correctly and detect it as string? run it
class HMap<K, V> {
  constructor(items: Record<string, V>)
  constructor(items: [K, V][])
  constructor(items: Record<string, V> | [K, V][]) {
  }
}

const h = new HMap({a: 1, b: 2}) // => HMap<unknown, number>


The only place K is used is [K, V][], and you’re not passing a [K, V][]. Did you mean to write Record<K, V>?

@Ry- the Record<K, V> won't work, try it, it will complains that K is not string

You can treat your K as a property key with the intersection:
Playground
class HMap<K, V> {
  constructor(items: Record<K & string, V>)
  constructor(items: [K, V][])
  constructor(items: Record<string, V> | [K, V][]) {
  }
}

const h = new HMap({a: 1, b: 2}) // => const h: HMap<"a" | "b", number>


Thanks, but it doesn't work in some cases const h = new HMap({a: 1, b: 2} as Record<string, number>) // => const h: HMap<unknown, number>

@AlexCraft i don't understand why you'd need this, moreover as is code smell in many cases
